# ffmpeg permission denied in android studio?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to merge an audio in video using ffmpeg of the following dependency but getting the permission denied error.

```
 Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.example.mytestapp/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied
```

Dependency I am using

```
 implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

I am using following code to merge an audio into the video. I added the dependency and provided the path of the video. I also placed the ffpmeg.exe into the assets folder

```
        package com.example.mytestapp.Activity;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import com.example.mytestapp.R;
    import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler;
    import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg;
    import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    
    public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
        Context context;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    
        }
        protected Boolean doInBackground() {
            String ffmpegPath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/ffmpeg";
            Log.e("called ", ffmpegPath);
    
            String vpath = " /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20230325_083306.mp4";
            String aPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/Seesekadil.mp3";
    
            String oPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/202304_15-223653rangeela.mp4";
            String[] cmd = {"-i", vpath, "-i", aPath, "-shortest", oPath};
            try {
                FFmpeg.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        Log.e("Started", "yes");
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String message) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {
                        Log.e("Failed ", "yes");
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String message) {
                        Log.e("Success ", "yes");
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });
            } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            checkPermission();
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "ffmpeg");
            if (!file.canExecute()) {
                file.setExecutable(true);
            }
            doInBackground();
    
        }
    
        private void checkPermission() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return;
            }
            // request camera permission if it has not been grunted.
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
    
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 1:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "permission has been grunted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity3.this, "[WARN] permission is not grunted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    
    }
```